# Can I recreate a .torrent file from a torrent in uTorrent

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

If I have a torrent that I have been seeding for a long time in uTorrent (that I no longer have the .torrent for) that I would like to remove and then use in the future, or transfer to another PC is it possible for me to retrieve its .torrent file, for the items contained, even if I do not have the original .torrent available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to retrieve the torrent file from here if using Windows: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent`

Otherwise you can **create a new torrent** using "create torrent" under `File` menu, then selecting the downloaded torrent folder you have on your computer.  However, this new torrent will not be treated as the same torrent you downloaded before.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: "Else you can create your own torrent" - Yes, but it will be a new torrent even if you add all files, and you cannot join the original torrent's swarm and reseed it in future.

Comment: Yes Of-course @Karan, But the only way to get the same torrent back is to download from source or get it from app data folder as on top.. If both the above or not possible and still want to share then we need to create our own torrent which will be separate from the previous...